# Multisites placed inside sub site folder?

Tags: multi-sites

I have my main plain html site in root folder and drupal site in sub site folder. Now I am wanting to create multisites and wonder if  sub sites can reside in drupal sub site sites folder?

www.subdrupal.mainsite.com/subdrupal/sites/sub2drupal  etc.

Or must I start again as it can only be www.subdrupal.mainsite.com/sites/subdrupal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. It is possible to run drupal multisites as a subdirectory even if your Drupal installation is in a subdirectory itself.

> Side note: the /sites/ directory in your examples is not necessary.

Given that your main Drupal install is accesible at `domain.com/drupal` the solution is to use symlinks to tell your webserver that the document root for `domain.com/drupal/multisite` is the same as your main drupal install (`domain.com/drupal`).

1. The first step is to create a directory for the multisite. The syntax is a little different for subdirectory multisites: `domain.com.multisite`. So, inside your `/sites` directory, you will have something like this:

   `-|/sites

   --|----/all

   --|----/default

   --|----/domains.com.multisite`
2. Place a copy of `default.settings.php` in `domains.com.multisite` and rename it to `settings.php`.
3. Then create the symlink described above by running the following command from your main website's docroot (not Drupal's docroot, the main website's docroot - usually `public_html` or something similar):

   `ln -s [drupal-directory-name] [multisite-directory-name]`

Or, using the names in our example above:

```
ln -s drupal multisite
```

See [Drupal's multisite documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) for more information.

Comment: Wonderful! Very succinct answer, I had read about it since posting this and what you describe is exactly what I've read except more to the point. :)

Comment: Hi again, have quick question, if drupal is in domain.com/drupal but is pointing to drupal.domain.com then could not other subs go in same html folder as drupal? so var/www/html/drupal, drupal2 and so on? creating the symlink from within same folder rather than places other subsites in drupal/sites/domain.com.sub (which would really be drupal/sites/sub.domain.com. Sorry to bother..